# Is it possible to save a product without without firing events?

Tags: product, import, event-observer

There is an event that fires after a product import (And we run this update on the product import). Is it possible to make this save without extra events firing?

```
/*UPDATE UNIT COST*/
                    if ($unit_cost > 0) {
                        try {
                            $product->setData('cost', $unit_cost);
                            $product->save();
                            Mage::log("SKU {$sku} cost was updated to {$unit_cost}", null, 'custom.log');
                        }
                        catch (Exception $e) {
                            Mage::logException($e);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: This link has the exact same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724479/magento-save-products-without-events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try updating your code to use the `saveAttribute` function:

```
$product->setData('cost', $unit_cost);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'cost');
```

This should not fire any of the normal events fired when saving a product and should also speed up your code.

For EAV models the function `saveAttribute` will do exactly what it name suggests and save a single attribute without you having to call save on the model. It will work out what attribute and tables your are working with and in the end run either:

```
$adapter->insertOnDuplicate($table, $data, array('value'));
```

OR

```
$adapter->delete($table, array('value_id IN (?)' => $valueIds));
```

Comment: But I will still have to call  $product->save() correct?

Comment: No this will just updated the single attribute for that model without having to call save.

Comment: Yes Thank you David - This work magically

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving a model in magento, you will fire many events, no way to turn them off, unless you modify core code.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to disable the event by using the event type `disabled`. For example:

```
    <events>
        <product_save>
            <observers>
                <reports>
                    <type>disabled</type>
                </reports>
            </observers>
        </product_save>
    </events>
```

Reference: http://www.atwix.com/magento/observers-reality-or-fiction/